Webpage displayed corrected date for me, but the code was updated later – why?
I visited my company's website this morning and it had an error in the date displayed. The website originally said "Saturday, November 24, 2024" (which is incorrect, as November 24, 2024 is a Sunday). However, when I visited the website this morning, I saw the correct date "Saturday, November 23, 2024".
Later in the evening, my colleague wrote that she had only just fixed it this evening and entered the correct date of November 23. Other users who had visited the website earlier that day still saw the incorrect date (November 24, 2024), while I saw November 23.
Is there any way this is possible? Thank you.
I want to know how something like this could happen. Is there any automatic browser fix possible or something else?
